# Sectioned GridView in android

Tags: android, gridview

I am following this https://github.com/madhu314/sectionedgridview for sectioned gridview. 
In data_item.xml I have checkbox instead of imagebutton. I want to check multiple items and then send the checked item to another activity.
The problem that I am facing is, that when i scroll the listview up or down, the checkboxes that are checked get unchecked and different checkboxes are checked.
I need help regarding this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = null;
    boolean isSectionheader = isSectionHeader(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (isSectionheader) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.section_header, null);
        } else {
            LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.list_row, null);
            v = ll;
            ll = (LinearLayout) ll.findViewById(R.id.row_item);
            // add childrenCount to this
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChildrenInRow; i++) {
                // add a child
                View child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.data_item, null);
                ll.addView(child, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        gridItemSize, gridItemSize));

                if (i < numberOfChildrenInRow - 1) {
                    // now add space view
                    View spaceItem = new View(mContext);
                    ll.addView(spaceItem, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                            childrenSpacing[i], ll.getHeight()));
                }
            }

        }

    } else {
        v = convertView;
    }

    String sectionName = whichSection(position);

    if (isSectionheader) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) v;
        tv.setText(sectionName);
    } else {
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) v;
        LinearLayout rowPanel = (LinearLayout) ll.findViewById(R.id.row_item);
        View divider = ll.findViewById(R.id.row_item_divider);
        divider.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // check if this position corresponds to last row
        boolean isLastRowInSection = isLastRowInSection(position);
        int positionInSection = positionInSection(position);

        Cursor c = sectionCursors.get(sectionName);

        // --
        int cursorStartAt = numberOfChildrenInRow * positionInSection;

        // set all children visible first
        for (int i = 0; i < 2 * numberOfChildrenInRow - 1; i++) {
            // we need to hide grid item and gap
            View child = rowPanel.getChildAt(i);
            child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // leave alternate
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                // its not gap
                if (c.moveToPosition(cursorStartAt)) {
                    String dataName = c.getString(0);
                    TextView tv = (TextView) child
                            .findViewById(R.id.data_item_text);
                    tv.setText(dataName);
                }

                // set listener on image button
                checkbox = (CheckBox) child
                        .findViewById(R.id.data_item_image);
                ButtonViewHolder holder = new ButtonViewHolder();
                holder.sectionName = sectionName;
                holder.positionInSection = cursorStartAt;
                holder.parent = child;
                holder.position = position;
                checkbox.setTag(holder);
                checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
                cursorStartAt++;

            }
        }
        checkbox.setChecked(mSparseBooleanArray.get(position));
        if (isLastRowInSection) {
            divider.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            // check how many items needs to be hidden in last row
            int sectionCount = sectionCursors.get(sectionName).getCount();

            int childrenInLastRow = sectionCount % numberOfChildrenInRow;

            if (childrenInLastRow > 0) {
                int gaps = childrenInLastRow - 1;

                for (int i = childrenInLastRow + gaps; i < rowPanel
                        .getChildCount(); i++) {
                    // we need to hide grid item and gap
                    View child = rowPanel.getChildAt(i);
                    child.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

            }
        }

    }


    return v;
}
```

Comment: can you post a piece of code related to your gridview adapter

Comment: Have a look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, you need to select the multiple images and after that you need to do an action (like coping selected images, delete / upload etc). So for that you need to hold the selection image positions as well as you need to change the selection color too..

For that i simply created an adapter, it having the multiple image selection and various methods to get the selected images and select all/ de select all options.. In this i controlled all the possibilities think so.. If it is the same means, change your adapter class like this..

Here is my adapter class:

```
public class LocalFilesUploadAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

    private final HashMap<Integer, Boolean> myChecked = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

    private final Activity _activity;
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();

    ArrayList<String> listPaths;
    ArrayList<String> listNames;

    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public LocalFilesUploadAdapter( Context context,
        Activity activity,
        ArrayList<String> filePaths,
        ArrayList<String> fileNames,
        ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps )
    {

        this._activity = activity;
        this.listPaths = filePaths;
        this.listNames = fileNames;
        this.bitmaps = bitmaps;

        inflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );

        for( int i = 0; i < filePaths.size(); i++ )
        {
            myChecked.put( i,
                           false );
        }

    }

    public void toggleChecked( int position )
    {
        if( myChecked.get( position ) )
        {
            myChecked.put( position,
                           false );
        }
        else
        {
            myChecked.put( position,
                           true );
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void selectAllItems( int position )
    {

        myChecked.put( position,
                       true );

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void deSelectAllItems( int position )
    {

        myChecked.put( position,
                       false );

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public List<Integer> getCheckedItemPositions()
    {
        List<Integer> checkedItemPositions = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for( int i = 0; i < myChecked.size(); i++ )
        {
            if( myChecked.get( i ) )
            {
                ( checkedItemPositions ).add( i );
            }
        }

        return checkedItemPositions;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getCheckedItems()
    {
        ArrayList<String> checkedItems = new ArrayList<String>();

        // ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> checkedItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        for( int i = 0; i < myChecked.size(); i++ )
        {
            if( myChecked.get( i ) )
            {

                String pathName = listPaths.get( i );

                ( checkedItems ).add( pathName );
            }
        }

        return checkedItems;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getCheckedItemNames()
    {
        ArrayList<String> checkedItems = new ArrayList<String>();

        // ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> checkedItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        for( int i = 0; i < myChecked.size(); i++ )
        {
            if( myChecked.get( i ) )
            {

                String imageName = listNames.get( i );

                ( checkedItems ).add( imageName );
            }
        }

        return checkedItems;
    }

    public boolean selectAll()
    {

        for( int i = 0; i < listPaths.size(); i++ )
        {
            selectAllItems( i );
        }

        return false;

    }

    public boolean deSelectAll()
    {

        for( int i = 0; i < listPaths.size(); i++ )
        {
            deSelectAllItems( i );
        }

        return false;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if( 0 == listPaths.size() )
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return this.listPaths.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem( int position )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.listPaths.get( position );
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId( int position )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView( final int position,
            View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent )
    {

        View row = convertView;

        if( row == null )
        {
            row = inflater.inflate( R.layout.gridview_item,
                                    null );
        }

        Log.d( "debug",
               "position" + position );

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById( R.id.grid_image );
        CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById( R.id.img_checkBox );

        imageView.setImageBitmap( bitmaps.get( position ) );

        checkbox.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick( View v )
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                toggleChecked( position );
            }
        } );

        Boolean checked = myChecked.get( position );
        if( checked != null )
        {
            checkbox.setChecked( checked );
        }

        imageView.setOnClickListener( new OnImageClickListener( position ) );

        return row;
    }

    class OnImageClickListener implements OnClickListener
    {

        int _postion;

        // constructor
        public OnImageClickListener( int position )
        {
            this._postion = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick( View v )
        {
            // on selecting grid view image
            // launch full screen activity

            toggleChecked( _postion );

        }

    }

}
```

Hope it vll help's you

Comment: The solution for a simple listview using a base adaptor is pretty straight forward. In my case i have divided the listview into sections and and handling checkboxes in my case is not that simple.